# Keep last selected item in drop downs

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4, sqlalchemy

I have bootstrap drop down lists to select items from a MySQL table,  it all works fine. My only issue is that the drop downs reset to their default values (obviously, as I've set defaults in the HTML). What I would like is for them to keep their last selected value so users don't have to keep re-selecting the same item if they wish to edit them.

Below is a selection of the code to give you an idea of how it is, there are a few drop downs, this shows just one and then the Python code in my app.py.

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" name="item-select" id="item-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
    <option value="long_sleave_1/4_zip">Long Sleave 1/4 zip</option>
    <option value="ls_comfort_tee">Long Sleave Comfort Tee</option>
    <option value="ss_comfort_tee">Short Sleave Comfort Tee</option>
    <option value="team_polo">Team Polo</option>
    <option value="run_tank">Run Tank</option>
    <option value="run_tee">Run Tee</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm text-right">
    <button name="subbutton" value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
</div>
```

```python
gender=request.form["gender-select"]
item=request.form["item-select"]
size=request.form["size-select"]
stock=con.execute(get_stock.format(item,size,gender)).fetchall()   
size=request.form["size-select"]   
amount=request.form["clothingamount"]
in_out=request.form['in_out']
stock=con.execute(get_stock.format(item,size,gender)).fetchall()
con.close()
engine.dispose()
return render_template('stock_check.html', stock=stock)
```

Comment: Btw. `get_stock.format(item,size,gender)` looks like you've opened yourself up for SQL injection. Please don't format values to SQL query strings, ever. Use proper placeholders and pass the arguments to `execute()`.

Comment: yeah, as this is all in house and only used by a handful of people I've not really been too concerned by that but it's good to point out! I've actually fixed that now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the selected item to HTML template from Flask and add `selected` attribute if the values are matched.

I am showing simplified example of this approach without database connection.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/item-selection", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def form_handler():
    previous_data = {"selected_item":"team_polo"}
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html", previous_data=previous_data)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        result = request.form["item-select"]
        return render_template("index.html", previous_data=previous_data,
                               result=result)
```

`index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="submitted_value">
      {% if result %}
        Selected Item: {{ result }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <form action="/item-selection" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="item-select">Select item</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="item-select" id="item-select">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="hoodie" {% if previous_data["selected_item"] == "hoodie"%} selected {% endif %} >Hoodie</option>
          <option value="long_sleave_1/4_zip" {% if previous_data["selected_item"] == "long_sleave_1/4_zip"%} selected {% endif %}>Long Sleave 1/4 zip</option>
          <option value="ls_comfort_tee" {% if previous_data["selected_item"] == "ls_comfort_tee"%} selected {% endif %}>Long Sleave Comfort Tee</option>
          <option value="ss_comfort_tee" {% if previous_data["selected_item"] == "ss_comfort_tee"%} selected {% endif %}>Short Sleave Comfort Tee</option>
          <option value="team_polo" {% if previous_data["selected_item"] == "team_polo"%} selected {% endif %}>Team Polo</option>
          <option value="run_tank" {% if previous_data["selected_item"] == "run_tank"%} selected {% endif %}>Run Tank</option>
          <option value="run_tee" {% if previous_data["selected_item"] == "run_tee"%} selected {% endif %}>Run Tee</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

Assume we have already stored `team_polo` as selected item in database.

Before submitting the form the value will be selected by default:

[image: before submission of form]

After submitting the form show the selected value:

[image: after submitting the form]

**Alternative and better solution:**

Handling each value of a select item is error prone. You can use a Flask extension to handle the form values from database and also in HTML form.

Check [documentation of flask-wtf's package](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for details.